# request body undefined in node express

Tags: node.js, post, express, request

In node express when I try to access the post value from the form it shows request body undefined error.
Here is my code,

```
http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    var hostname = req.headers.host.split(":")[0];
    var pathname = url.parse(req.url).pathname;

  if (pathname==="/login" && req.method ==="POST") {
  console.log("request Header==>" + req.body.username );

}).listen(9000, function() {
    console.log('http://localhost:9000');
});
```

Please any one help me to find why the request body shows undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not using `express` for the web server and just plain http. Use the [body](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body) module.

Answer (score 1):

Enable [body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) middleware first

```
var express = require('express')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

var app = express()

// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.use(function (req, res) {
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain')
  res.write('you posted:\n')
  res.end(JSON.stringify(req.body, null, 2))
})
```

Comment: We are using the same middle ware but the server is http proxy